# Getting a value from HTML with results from a while loop using php mysqli and jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysqli

I have searched, but I can't seem to find an answer to my question, and I've tried various solutions.

Essentially I have a While Loop that's populated correctly. I search for a term/keyword and I get a list of what I want.

Inside the results I have used the code in my 'fetch-result.php', which uses AJAX to pull a live search query:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 $mystuff = $row['stuff'];
 $stuffid = $row['rid'];
 echo '<a value="'.$stuffid.'">'.$mystuff.'</a><br />';
}
```

So I get the results as 'links'.

Now I'm stuck at the part where I want to be able to click on the result and it should throw back the stuffid value in the HTML portion of the code so that it returns it inside a textarea.

Here's the code for that:

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="2" placeholder="Write here" id="input" name="query"></textarea>
```

And the script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){
            return "Hello world!";
        });
        $("a").click(function(event){
            $("textarea").html(event.result);
        });  
    });
</script>
```

Please note that the code above is my attempt at trying to figure this out on my own, ergo the 'Hello world!'

What I am trying to do is that when you click on the solution it should automatically update the text where the user is writing and autocomplete it. I'm trying to code it like a tagging system, but inclusive of entire phrases, which include various punctuation. Most solutions I've found explode portions of the text and don't suit my needs. I've even used abnormal characters, but that also did not seem to work properly either.

I've used several different onClick(); functions but none of them seem to work when I fetch results from the while loop. I've put the scripts inside the page where the searches are being called from, and not inside the search process page itself.

For example, the search below is one that I attempted to use but did not work with the While loop. Worked fine when I coded it directly into the HTML.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 $mystuff = $row['stuff'];
 $stuffid = $row['rid'];
 echo '<a value="'.$stuffid.'" onclick="$(/'#test/').click( function() { alert(/'clicked/'); });">'.$mystuff.'</a><br />';
}
```

I've tried to use FULLTEXT search in MySQL, but I can't seem to get MATCH to work properly, so I've worked around it for now. I've already converted the table and modified the columns and changed the engine to ISAM.

So I'm stuck. If anyone can help me and point me in the right direction, or point out where I have gone wrong, I'd be eternally grateful.

Oh, and as to what I'm doing, I'm trying to create a hardcoded translator where words and phrases are manually coded by me. And no, I don't want to use Google Translate because it doesn't translate phrases correctly and it doesn't do the language I want anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem you're having is that the jQuery click handler is not binding properly. This is because your click handler is only registering upon links that are already present in the DOM when the script runs. If this script runs at page load, it will only pick up on links in your HTML, not any that are obtained dynamically with AJAX.

The solution is to use [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Let's say `#parent` is a container that will hold all the links. Then, use:

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'a', null, function(event) {
   // processing goes here
});
```

Comment: Supposedly I have a <div> marked:
    `<div id="searchresultdata" class="faq-articles"></div>`
Would your code therefore look like this:
    `$('#searchresultdata').on('click', 'a', null, function(event) {
      alert("click!");
    });`

Comment: Doesn't work. I've even changed the code to: `$('#searchresultdata').on("click", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
 });` I just can't see where I'm going wrong!

Comment: `<div onclick="alert('.$id.')"value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</div><br />` works. It's throwing back the correct values for each instance, so I guess you're right that the script isn't being initialized properly somewhere. So that solves one part of my problem... thanks again.

Comment: Hmm. instead of `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ })` try `jQuery(function($) { /* code here */ });`

Comment: Strange. It works only with some fields, not with others. For example, it works when I throw back a MySQL array of integers by clicking on the text, but not when I try to use text. Is it because of the whites spaces?

Comment: No idea. Best thing you can do is fire up a DOM inspector/JS console (Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug for Firefox) and investigate from there. You might find that setting `value` on the `a` tags might be causing trouble too; it's not valid HTML for links to have the `value` attribute.

Comment: I gave up. I found another way of doing this that works better. Thanks for your help anyway.